# Is there a limit to the total number of days I can be in Australia on my visitor visa?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, australia, visa-expiration

I hold the eVisitor (subclass 651) visa, dated Sept 12th 2017 and I understand that I can enter Australia anytime for up to 90 days per entry.

Is there a limit of the total days within the visa period?

I travelled there, and will enter, as follows:

- 15th-30th Sept 2017 = 15 days
- 29th Nov - 20th Dec 2017 = 23 days
- 23rd Jan - 9th March 2018 = 46 days
- 29th March - 9th April 2018 = 12 days

The total will be 96 days.

How many more days could I spend in Australia until the visa expires on the 14th Sept 2018?

Answer (score 1):

There is no formal limit on the number of days you can stay in Australia, as long as you leave within 3 months per entry.

However, if you come too often and/or stay too long the authorities may suspect you are not a genuine temporary visitor and may cancel the visa as a result.

Comment: thank you very much about this information, Im in a new relation with Tim from BNE, we me last September and since then visiting vice versa, anyhow in 2018 we have a lot of plans inside Australia, selling Tim's house and furthermore things to be done, and that's why we try to find out what is the best option for that - visa wise. He will retire before the end of 2018 , from 2019 onwards we will divide our time between my homes in TH and Germany and Australia. tks again rgds Mag